# Arduino Wifi Works one way but not the other? (ESP32) (Possible Variable Type Problem)

Tags: wifi, esp32

I am working on a code that accepts input from serial monitor and connects to Wifi, and have been getting issues.

my SSID for my wifi is "SamF" but for some reason arduino only likes it when I initialize at the top, not when I accept it from serial monitor even though they are the same..

Example The below code works:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "SamF"; //OR const char* = "SamF"
char pass[] = "secretPassword";
void setup()
{
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
}
void loop () {}
```

The Code Below Does not work..

```
#include <WiFi.h>
char pass[] = "secretPassword";
void setup()
{
ssidSerial = my code that receives Serial input and converts to char

for(int k=0;k<=3;k++){
ssidPlaceHolder[k]=ssidSerial[k];
}
const char* ssid = ssidPlaceHolder;
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
}
void loop () {}
```

Everything compiles fine, I debugged by using Serial.print and they are both displaying "SamF" and sizeof(ssid) for both is 4... so I am not sure why one works and the other doesn't? any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help, and if anyone needs the code after I am done I will be more than glad to share it on git!

Comment: add a terminating 0 to ssidPlaceholder end. 4 char string needs 5 char array to have the 5th position set to 0

Comment: why do you copy the string from ssidSerial to ssidPlaceHolder and what for is the assignment to `ssid` pointer?

Comment: Thanks for response Juraj, I will try add the terminating 0 to the variable once I get home and will let you know what happens, I copied it over because ssidSerial adds garbage data at the end, because I am using Bluetooth Serial, ssidSerial is "SamF   garbage symbol" and I needed "SamF" that is why I am coping it over.

Comment: just to clarify more,  receiving after receiving Bluetooth serial data the variable ssidSerial becomes "SamF   garbage symbol/data" of length 10 which I thought would mess it up.  the wifi library accepts data in the form of a pointer which is why it's there, I know its the same thing as just ssidPlaceHolder but I thought it would help

Comment: perhaps you send the new line character(s) \n or \r\n, not garbage

Comment: interesting... I will print out the hex value to see what exactly the additional data is

Comment: ->So the problem was that I had not terminated the char, I didn't know you needed to manually terminate them for some reason. Thanks for answering, please answer the question below so that I can select your answer and you can get reputation!      
->Also, If you are wondering or curious, the "garbage data" at the end of the array was some symbols and negative acknowledgments it was ",@NAK?  NAK". Which might be coming from the Bluetooth of the ESP32? maybe it is how Bluetooth ends it's message, I am not too familiar with networking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic string in C is an array of characters terminated by a 0. All functions taking char* or const char* use this 0 to determine the end of the string, because there is no other information about the length of that string.

In your question you copy characters from one characters buffer to other, but you do not set the terminating 0, so the function `begin` takes the data after the `pass` pointer until some random memory location with 0.